# How can something like the “passwd” file contain a shell?

Tags: shell

I was doing some reading, and in Jon Erickson’s [“Hacking, 2nd Edition: The Art of Exploitation”](https://books.google.com/books?id=0FW3DMNhl1EC&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89&dq=%22passwd%20file%20contains%20account%20information%20for%20every%20user%20on%20the%20system,%22&source=bl&ots=tu0zJXDUSs&sig=46AMDNxFScPv6tF83MnYX0GPb1k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9k8bVbTtA5DdsASx2IDIDQ&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22passwd%20file%20contains%20account%20information%20for%20every%20user%20on%20the%20system%2C%22&f=false) on page 89 I read that:

> passwd file contains account information for every user on the system,
>   including each user’s default login shell

How can something contain a shell? I thought that was more or less something that you use to interact with the system, not something contained like a file? What actually is a shell then?

Comment: Where did you read this? They may have meant it as a template for logging in or something.

Answer (score 5):

Simple, when you “login” with a user the user’s default shell is executed. The `passwd` file contains this information (i.e. `/bin/csh`, `/bin/bash`, or the like). It is one of the fields in the file which is used.  Below is an example entry:

```
jsmith:x:1001:1000:Joe Smith,Room 1007,(234)555-8910,(234)555-0044,email:/home/jsmith:/bin/sh
```

Notice the very last field contains `/bin/sh`.  When this user logs in this is the default “shell” that is executed for the user to interact with.

I think you are misinterpreting the meaning. It doesn’t literally “contain” a user’s shell in that it occurs “inside” this file. It only holds a field for each entry indicating which “shell” binary will be executed by default for the user to interact with once they have been authenticated.

Comment: So it basically contains the shell code that is executed?  I understand that, I can't believe I didn't understand the other explanation.  Too much reading for one day, I suppose.

Comment: @WhiteMask There is no... "code" that is executed.  It is simply information that is used during and after authentication.  You may want to just read through the passwd man file if you want a better understanding of what it contains.

Comment: @WhiteMask As Goblinlord has mentioned (and commented correctly) - the last entry simply information advising "what kind of shell to run when this user logs in". In the current answer when jsmith logs in, it will automatically open /bin/sh shell. Some people may opted to put /bin/tcsh or /bin/zsh. Or in some cases, /bin/nobody (in which case they can't login). It simply refers to a location where the shell executable is stored. You may even have /media/seagate/sh or something. /bin/sh is one of the default depends on your linux flavour.